# Positive semidefinite matrix with 0 on diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix

> If I have a Hessian matrix
> $  \begin{bmatrix}
>     0 & 1 \\
>     1 & 0 
>   \end{bmatrix}
> $
> might someone help me understand why this is not positive semidefinite?

My understanding that if for any $q(x) - x^TAx$, $A$ is PSD if $q(x) \le 0$ for every $x \in R^n$.

Comment: Take $x=(-1,1)$

Comment: ah! ok thanks so much... for some reason I was thinking $x$ was all the same values. Which is clearly not the case. Thanks @MichalAdamaszek

Comment: suggested exercise: if a matrix is real symmetric PSD and has a zero on the kth diagonal, then all of row $k$ (and column $k$) must be zero.